Teradata SQL - table has a list of activation and deactivation activity dates on individual lines, can they be combined to show full activity time?
The table is laid out like this
LastName
FirstName
AccountNumber
ServiceCode
ActivityCode
ActivityDate

The activity code is either A for activate and D for deactivate
Activity date is a date field of YYYY-MM-DD.
The combination of last name, first name, and account number is unique to the particular person so that is the main identifier.
For the table there will be individual lines for activations and deactivations, so for example
Doe, John, 1234, 5678, A, 2022-01-14
Doe, John, 1234, 5678, D, 2024-06-22

So here John Doe activated service 5678 on Jan 1 2022 and then deactivated it June 22 2024.
There can also be an activation with no deactivation as it means the service is still active, so an entry like this:
Doe, Jane, 9876, 5678, A, 2024-01-01

This person activated the service in January of this year and never deactivated it.
What I am trying to do is find a way to put it all together so I can show how many of each service code was active in a given month. The table is a transactional table so it only has info of the day the even occurred in order. So on the John Doe example there could be a million lines between that activation and the deactivation. I have to somehow link the activate date to the deactivate date to show the time period it is all active.
Like a line of
Last Name, First Name, Account Number, ServiceCode, ActivateDate, DeactivateDate

But also take into account the DeactivateDate could be blank if there is no activity code of D associated with that service.
I am thinking on how to do a left join maybe the table with itself?  Like a name = name, account = account, and code = code and then one would be the A and the other the D, but if there is no deactivate then it would join on nothing?  Can you join a table on itself like this?  I would have to distinguish between the activity codes.
I am having issues with the null values when there is no deactivation date.

You are on the right track - something like select <stuff> from (select * from table where activitycode= 'A') a left join (select * from table where activitycode= 'D') d on a.name = d.name and ...

Is there always a single A row followed by a single optional B row? SELECT LEAD(CASE WHEN ActivityCode = 'D' THEN ActivityDate END) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY LastName, FirstName, AccountNumber ORDER BY ActivityDate) FROM mytable QUALIFY ActivityCode = 'A'
